# Non Negative Tensor Tucker Decomposition Error Degradation

Tags: tensor-products, positivity, tensor

I have been working on iterative decomposition methods of tensors with non negativity constraints. I have noticed that $\textbf{N}$on negative $\textbf{T}$ensor $\textbf{F}$actorization "NTF" which is the normal canonical polyadic decomposition with negative constraints to have better estimation error compared to the $\textbf{N}$on negative $\textbf{T}$ucker $\textbf{D}$ecomposition "NTD".

I have noted that tensor of rank 1 can produce NTF and NTD decomposition of same tolerance while for Rank = 2, the error is already doubled for NTD while the same for NTF. Taking into consideration that the only difference between both decomposition is the core tensor existing in NTD while having a super identity tensor in NTF.

> For example for 3 dimension tensor ${\cal{X}}_0 \in {\mathbb{R}}^{I
> \times J \times K}$
>
> NTF ${\cal{X}}_{est} = \underset{R \times R \times R}{\cal{I}} \times_1 \underset{I \times R}{\mathbf{A}_+} \times_2 \underset{J \times R}{\mathbf{B}_+}
>  \times_3 \underset{K \times R}{\mathbf{C}_+}$
>
> NTD ${\cal{X}}_{est}  = \underset{R \times R \times R}{\cal{C}_+} \times_1 \underset{I \times R}{{\mathbf{U}_1}_+} \times_2
>  \underset{J \times R}{{\mathbf{U}_2}_+} \times_3 \underset{K \times R}{{\mathbf{U}_3}_+}$
>
> $\cal{I}$ is a super identity tensor
>
> $\cal{C}$ is a full core tensor
>
> $\mathbf{A}_+$ is a matrix consists of non negative elements
>
> The error function $ Err = \dfrac{\| {\cal{X}_0} -
>  {\cal{X}_{est}}\|_H}{ \| {\cal{X}_0} \|_H}  $
>
> $\| {\cal{X}} \|_H$ is the high order norm based on Euclidean
>   distance of tensors corresponding to the frobenius norm to matrices
>
> $\times_n$ is the n-mode product tensor based

My only interpretation that having a full core tensor with positivity constraints is causing an increase in error but I need some kind of prove or detailed math explanation. I would appreciate it if someone has encountered such a problem or can give me a starting point.